# Mono console app as daemon take 100% cpu

Tags: c#, mono

I have a console app (I know it should be a service) with a loop at the end so it never stops:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It run perfectly on a Raspberry Pi using mono (raspbian wheezy) but since I upgraded to the Pi 2 with Raspbian Jessie, it use 100% cpu when started as a Daemon.

It seems that Readline() is always returning an empty line. Any idea? My init.d script is really simple for testing purpose:

```
cd /myAppDir/
mono MyApp.exe &
exit 0
```

I tried with nohup, with/without the `&` at the end, without success

[Edit]
I can't use Thread.Sleep since I have a Timer pooling the UART. An easy solution would be to create another thread for all the work and just do the Sleep in the main thread but I would like to understand why it doesn't work like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it uses 100% cpu when started as a Daemon.

I do not know how are you starting your process as a daemon but typically, daemon processes redirect `stdin` to `/dev/null`.

Null device yields EOF immediately, so `Console.ReadLine()` will never block.

I guess (I have no Raspbian), the way of running daemons changed from Raspbian Wheezy to Jessie.

Comment: That's what I thought, and that's why I was surprised to see it work on Wheezy... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only need this before finish Main(string[] args)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
     //call method for daemon before while
     while (true)
     {
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
}
```

with this your app not will take 100% CPU usage

Comment: This is an old question, but if you read it completely you will see that I said "I can't use Thread.Sleep because....". All our projects use .net core now